# JW player Retrieving Captions from youtube video

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, jwplayer, closed-captions

Im playing a video from youtube on my site and want to be able to use these captions at my domain. 
[JW player documentation about captions can be found here:](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1407438-adding-closed-captions)

Now here's the problem: 
JW player's built in translation support looks like this:

```
tracks: [{ 
            file: "/assets/captions-en.vtt", 
            label: "English",
            kind: "captions",
            "default": true 
        },{ 
            file: "/assets/captions-fr.vtt", 
            kind: "captions",
            label: "French"
        }]
```

It uses a physical path to search for .vtt files.

My question is simply:
**How do i fetch captions from a youtube video and display them in JW player?**

Comment: That is not possible I'm afraid. We don't support that through their API.

Comment: If you own the video, you can set up your own script (outside of JWPlayer) that can download them dynamically and return them as a URL that JWPlayer can use; however, if you don't own the video, the YouTube captions are not available via the API.

Comment: I solved the fetching part from youtube, so now it looks like this               file: http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=sv&v=jFRj5uH3Jhc&fmt=vtt      When opened in browser, the .vtt file displays correclty but no captions show up in JW player.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [captions feature in API v3 to retrieve video captions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/captions).

Comment: I solved the fetching part from youtube, so now it looks like this file: http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=sv&v=jFRj5uH3Jhc&fmt=vtt When opened in browser, the .vtt file displays correctly but no captions show up in JW player. When i try using jwplayer's example from their documentation, http://bob.jwplayer.com/~randy/caption.vtt, it works. Am I handling the .vtt file from youtube wrong or what?